# Which memory settings to use for this MySQL server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, performance, virtualhost, memory

I've been looking in a lot of places so far but I couldn't find any articles about how much memory to allocate to MySQL based on server size.

I am about to deploy a website on a relatively small vserver with the following specs:
500 mb ram
20 gb SSD
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
1 virtual CPU (my provider doesn't specify speed).

With the server running idle (i.e website has no traffic), I get these values after rebooting:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVGcn.png]

It runs exclusively apache+mysql. The number of concurrent users is expected to be low for starters (<20).

What should be some sensible values for mysql's memory allocation for this case? And are there any other settings I can use to make sure the server resources are being used to their full extent?

Comment: You haven't got enough usage to worry about this. Come back when your server is actually being utilized.

Comment: thanks, I suspected the same as well but wanted to make sure.

Comment: You should create a swap partition. If the load on the server increases enough to fill up your memory, a swap partition will give you a performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

[Percona Configuration Wizard for MySQL](https://tools.percona.com/) is a nice tool to aid in MySQL configuration. It tries to provide a valid *my.ini* config file for your MySQL instance, based on many criteria like workload type, available RAM, CPU cores, MySQL version, etc. Requires registration.